# Can I make an <input> box have text that wraps?

Tags: html, css

I have an

```
<input type="text" />
```

box. The data in my box is quite long so I set the height to 100px. However the text just goes from left to right and does not wrap. Is there any way I could make it wrap?

Hoping for some good suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: One excellent way to make it wrap is to make it a `textarea` instead of an `input`.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? like the comment box in facebook that increases height as the text gets longer?

Comment: Yes I would like to have that kind of functionality as in facebook

Comment: <input type="text" id="Items_input" class="selectbox" autocomplete="off" readonly="" tabindex="0">

Comment: Facebook is using <textarea> as answered below by others.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will look into textarea to find out how I can make it meet my needs.

Comment: Check out [jQuery's AutoResize Plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) it should do what you need.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use a `<textarea>` instead for input text that wraps.

Answer (score 5):

For multiline input and wrapping text, use a `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't make an input element do that. Use textarea instead.

Answer (score 0):

With the style `attr`, or with CSS, you can do this:

```
<textarea 
    id="temp" 
    style="white-space: pre-wrap; height: 100px; width: 500px;"
>This is my text box. And it can wrap.</textarea>
```

The same thing can be done in jQuery with:

```
$('#dom_id').attr("style", "white-space: pre-wrap");
```

This will hold for both textbox and text area.

Comment: @Spartky: sorry.. indeed i added a textarea but the tag got cut off.. sorry for the poor editing.. am a newbie.. and if we want to stick to the controll(textbox or textarea) then css comes for our rescue.

Comment: @Sparky: Say i have a huge html and lot of input elements as text box. and my requirement is to change the input to multiline text box and increase the width. Instead of changing all the input elements to textarea, i can apply the css(widht and wrap) using jquery. if there is only one control, then as you said, textarea comes handy..